# What does this method signature mean?

Tags: java, templates, generics

I'm new in Java and faced with some code which I couldn't understand.
Here is some method declaration:

```
public <V> void method(Map<T,V>)
```

I've read about Generics in java and couldn't find any description to the part **`public <V> void`**

Can any one explain what does it mean?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Generic method. It defines a method-scoped type called `<V>`.

Also, it uses a type `<T>` which possibly has a class-scope.

For example, let's say you have this class, parametrized by some type `<T>`.

```
public class Something<T> {
    private T key;

    public Something(T key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public <V> V getValueForKey(Map<T, V> map) {
        return map.get(key);
    }
}
```

The `getValueFromKey()` method defines a `<V>` type and it will return the object in the provided Map, which corresponds to the `key` member. Just to clarify: in order to provide a good example the return type I'm using will be `<V>` not `void`, but it doesn't matter that much.

So, for example, if you have:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("One", 1);
map.put("Two", 2);

Something<String> something = new Something<String>("One");
Integer value = something.getValueForKey(map);
```

then the `getValueForKey()` will return an `Integer`, because this is the *value* type in the provided `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

A `Map<T, V>` holds keys of type `T` and values of type `V`. The method have to know of which type `T` and `V` are when the call is made. It seams that `T` is already given by the instance the method is called at, but `V` is unknown. Hence, `public <V> void method` denotes that the caller must provide the type of `V` when calling the method.